# Seam 3 modules - getting started

Tags: seam, maven-3, seam3

I need help getting setup on Seam 3 modules.  When I try to use the Seam 3 module, persistence, the JBoss Java EE 6 spec cannot be found.

I was reading that I need to use maven 3 or declare the repository where that artifact can be found.  I am using maven 3, but still no go.

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need help getting setup on Seam 3 modules. When I try to use the Seam 3 module, persistence, the JBoss Java EE 6 spec cannot be found.

Providing links, some `pom.xml` snippet or some error trace illustrating a problem is usually helpful.

> I was reading that I need to use maven 3 or declare the repository where that artifact can be found. I am using maven 3, but still no go.

Reading where? I highly doubt that using Maven 3 is required and Maven 3 won't magically resolve more dependencies than Maven 2. My guess is that you're just missing some repositories.

But since you didn't say anything about the what/how/where, I can only suggest to add the JBoss Public Repository Group (that contains also java.net artifacts):

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: I'll give that a try later.  It doesn't have the Seam 3 modules, but perhaps it will have the JBoss Java EE spec?  Why would maven 3 be required?

Comment: @Walter Do you have any link about Seam 3 modules that I can check (even a pom.xml in their svn repo would be nice). Regarding Maven 3, I really don't think it is required (unless they are using some specific Maven 3.x features but I'm not even sure they are already available).